# .staging folder created in node_modules while npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, out-of-memory, node-modules

I am facing some weird issue. Whenever I am doing `npm install` always a .staging folder is created in `node_modules` folder.
Can anyone help me on this.
I want to create `Angular 6` project.
I took the reference of [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12540) issue. But the answer was not clear to me.
How can create a swap file if `npm is out of memory`.

Comment: are you still facing this issue?

Comment: No, I uninstalled node and remove all node_modules files from my computer and again installed it. That resolved my issue.